# How to handle custom objects for @AfterReturning Aspect for Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

So, I have the next class:

```
public class MyCustomClass {

    private String someField;

    public String getSomeField() {
        return someField;
    }

    public void setSomeField(String someField) {
        this.someField = someField;
    }
}
```

I would like to handle methods that return an instance of this class:

```
@Aspect
public class CustomAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "execution(* com.*.*(..))",
            returning = "val")
    public void handleCustom(JoinPoint joinPoint, MyCustomClass val) {
        System.out.println(val.getSomeField());
    }

}
```

But it's working only if the type of **val** is **Object**:

```
 public void handleCustom(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object val) {//...}
```

I tried to make something like this:

```
  if (val instanceof MyCustomClass) {
        System.out.println(((MyCustomClass) val).getSomeField());
    }
```

But it doesn't work, in debug mode I saw that the type is ArrayList and it's empty.

I know, I'm a beginner in AOP, but Could you please advise some workarounds that could help me?

updated:

Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>
```

AspectConfig (imported to the Application class):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.aspect")
public class AspectConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomAspect customAspect () {
        return new CustomAspect ();
    }
}
```

I tried to use CustomAspect as a @Component as well.

The custom object is just a DTO that is taken from maven artifact and is obtained via rest request.

So, I DO NOT have problems if the type of **val** is Object, everything works fine. But I do want to have **MyCustomClass** there instead of Object. Is it possible?

update 2:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController{
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "dosmth")
    public ResponseEntity<?> doSmth() {
        SomeObject res = myService.doSmthAndGet();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(res, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}



@Service
public class MyService{
   public SomeObject doSmthAndGet() {
      return SomeObject.of(getMyCustomClass());
   }

   private MyCustomClass getMyCustomClass() {
      MyCustomClass result = new MyCustomClass();
      result.setSomeField("Hello, Stack!");
      return result;
   }


}
```

It seems that @AfterReturning doesn't work for my submethod:

```
private MyCustomClass getMyCustomClass()
```

It's only triggered by the method that was called from Controller:

```
 public SomeObject doSmthAndGet()
```

I tried to use different executions for @AfterReturning...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works with AspectJ. Are you using Spring AOP instead of AspectJ?

Comment: can you show how your advice is applied, BTW @AfterReturning does not need the jointpoint parameter

Comment: The code should work, declare `@Component` for your `@Aspect` and be sure it is scanned by Spring. I am assuming that `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` has been declared or through `Spring Boot` it has been enabled internally through the dependencies detection.

Comment: I provided maven dependencies. Annotations are taken from org.aspectj.lang.annotation package
@ManuelJordan I tried to use Component or Bean declaration, the result is the same

Comment: Just thinking, since you apply this point cut to interface, there may be many method that get adviced, Hence in runtime you may not have value instance as MyCustomClass. 

can you try specific method and try 
@AfterReturning(        pointcut="com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()",
        returning="val")

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` means you're using SpringAOP.

Comment: Could you post the class declaration with the method that returns the `MyCustomClass` object? I mean the expected object/class that must intercepted by `AOP`

Comment: So, it seems that the problems is that AfterReturning works for only one service method that is called from controller. But I want it to work for all service methods and submethods...